# Change Axis Labels font size in PowerPoint 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, office-2010

Hi I am using PowerPoint 2010 and I am trying to change font size of Axis labels in a chart using VBA but I am getting the following error.

"Method 'TextFram2' of object 'ChartFormat' failed"

The code I am using to change the font is below.

```
.Axes(xlCategory).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 10
```

This codes works fine in Microsoft Excel but does not work in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 12
```